# Unable to install locales package on debian (tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask:python3.8) docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, debian, amazon-ecs

I have this docker image I am trying to add the locales package to use in my flask app. The debian information says this package is available to debian (bulleye) but when I try to install it on the docker image it give this error:

```
#0 0.156 Package locales is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#0 0.156 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#0 0.156 is only available from another source
#0 0.156 
#0 0.156 E: Package 'locales' has no installation candidate
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install --no-install-recommends locales curl -y]: exit code: 100
```

I am have issues displaying the naira symbol on my app on a server hosted on aws via ecs services using fargate deployment. I have this code to do that:

```
def naira_symbol_generator(int_curr_symbol: str):
    """
    Function to generate the naira (or any other locale passed to it)
     currency code and symbol
    :param int_curr_symbol: NGN
    :return: Tuple of (int_curr_symbol [NGN], currency_symbol [])
    """
    try:
        import locale
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, int_curr_symbol)
        conv = locale.localeconv()
        return conv['int_curr_symbol'], conv['currency_symbol']
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f'naira_symbol_generator function error: {e}')
```

On the server I see this error:

```
2023-05-20 00:29:33 AM WAT] ERROR loggable: helper.py - naira_symbol_generator - 785 - [naira_symbol_generator function error: unsupported locale setting]
```

This is how I am using the function:

```
naira_symbol_generator("en_NG")[1]
```